# When I run Acronis on Hiren I cannot see the external hard drive plugged to USB port

Tags: acronis-trueimage, hiren

I have just bought a new laptop Lenovo G50-80 with Windows 8. I want to make an image of `C:` with the Acronis that comes with [Hiren](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) (True Image 2012).

It always worked with all my other computers which had Windows XP, but on my new laptop I plug the pendrive with Hiren in a port and the external hard drive—where I’m going to store the image—in a second USB port, then I run True Image but it doesn’t see the external hard drive.

If I plug it in a third USB port, then True Image gets stuck and I cannot run it.

Comment: are you using UEFI or CPM mode?

Comment: On my Bios I have set: Boot Mode (Legacy support); Boot Priority (UEFI First)

Comment: The other option to (UEFI First) is (Legacy First)

Comment: USB 2 or USB 3 ports being used

Comment: When I plug the external hard drive in a USB 2, True Image on HIren doesn't get stuck and runs correctly, but it cannot see the external HD. If I plug the external HD in a USB 3 socket, the True Image gets stuck in the process of opening up and comes to a halt.

Comment: Alright so.  Your system does not support booting to USB 3 devices by the sounds of it.  I am still not clear if you have a USB 3 port though.